# HTML layout issue in IE6, please help

Tags: html, css

Hello  I have an HTML document as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/styles.css" type="text/css" />
<title>::Model::</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header">
header
</div>

<div id="main">


<div id="left">


text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>

</div>
<div id="right">

text<br>
text<br>

</div>

</div>

<div id="footer">
footer
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS file is

```
#wrapper{
    margin:0px auto;
    width:1000px;
}

#header{
height:50px;
border:#CCCCCC solid 1px;
margin:2px;
padding:5px;
}

#main{
border:#990000 solid 1px;
margin:2px;
padding:5px;
overflow:auto;
}

#footer{
height:100px;
border:#CCCCCC solid 1px;
margin:2px;
padding:5px;
}

#left{
border:#CCCCCC solid 1px;
width:640px;
padding:4px;
float:left;

margin-right:2px;

}
#right{
float:right;
padding:4px;

border:#CCCCCC solid 1px;
width:320px;


}
```

This is working good in all browses except IE6, The main area should extend with dynamic contents.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why have you tagged this with `css3`? I don't see any CSS3 in the style sheet... and if there is some that I'm missing, that's your problem: IE6 does not support CSS3. It barely supports CSS2. Some might argue the quality of its CSS1 support, too, but that's another story. You might also tell us what it actually IS doing in IE6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `height: 100%` to `#main` - it's a known hack to make IE render `overflow: auto` properly.

Answer (score 2):

You should try [validating](http://validator.w3.org) your web page.  You've given it an xhtml doctype but you're definitely not writing valid xhtml.  Invalid code like that can frequently cause glitches in different browsers, though in the case of IE6 it may not work right anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If i recall correctly IE needs to have a width on the `div#main` if you want to clear it using the overflow method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack I use.  Remember, **this is a total hack and shouldn't be substituted for sound css.**  Paste this into the bottom of your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function setMainHeight(){
    var main = document.getElementById("main");
    var left = document.getElementById("left");
    var right = document.getElementById("right");

    main.style.height = (left.offsetHeight >= right.offsetHeight) ? left.offsetHeight + 'px' : right.offsetHeight + 'px';

}
setMainHeight();

</script>
```